# Replicate multidimensional NumPy array on an axis up-to specific value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional NumPy array with shape

> (2, 2)

Example array

> array([[1, 2],
> [3, 4]])

I am trying to have it copy on just the first axis until it reaches the shape:

> (5, 2)

Example result array

> array([[1, 2],
> [1, 2],
> [1, 2],
> [3, 4],
> [3, 4]])

np.repeat does the job but it has to be a multiple as it repeats everything

`np.repeat(arr, 3, axis=0)`

> array([[1, 2],
> [1, 2],
> [1, 2],
> [3, 4],
> [3, 4],
> [3, 4]])

giving a 6 by 2 array and not a 5 by 2 array

Answer (score 1):

```
np.repeat(arr, [3, 2], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am looking to repeat the entire array 3 times not each array a specific amount. I have a very large array with many more axis so I am looking for a method to repeat the entire array like the normal np.repeat(arr, no, axis) but crop the remaining part for example if I want to repeat a (1475,2) array to reach (3500, 2)

Comment: sorry for the confusing question, a normal crop can work after repeat now that I think about it but if there is a method that would be helpful

Comment: @AzariaGebremichael I guess cropping is the best way, you could dinamically build an array of repeats to give to `np.repeat` but I guess it's overengineering and it will probably be slower than cropping. 

Something like: `q, r = np.divmod(3500, 3); repeats = [3] * q + [r] + [0] * (len(arr) - q - 1); newarr = np.repeat(arr, repeats, axis=0)`